# How can I delete all documents from a collection without deleting the collection itself in firebase with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection called `mouse`, which has inside several documents, which I have added by clicking somewhere on my file. The fields each document of this collection have are: `'type', 'position x', 'position y'` and `'timestamp'`.

I have used the following code in order to save each click on the db (in other words to put a new element in the collection):

```
var setData = ref.set({
    'type': 'MC', 
    'x':  xPosition,
    'y': yPosition,
    'timestamp': firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
})
```

and this code in order to print out all documents in the collection:

```
db.collection("mouse").where("type", "==", "MC")
    .onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {
        var dataPoints = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
           dataPoints.push(doc.data().type + " " + doc.data().x + " " + doc.data().y + " " + doc.data().timestamp);
        });
        console.log("Current data in database: ", dataPoints.join(", ") + "\n");
    });
```

My question is now, how could I delete all these documents without deleting the collection? I appreciate any help you can provide

Comment: as far as I know, once all the documents from a collection are deleted, the collection itself also gets deleted.

Comment: You can't. Deleting all documents  will delete also its parent collection. That's how firebase works

Comment: @UsamaTahir do you know how I could delete some documents selectively then?

Comment: @elbertrivas do you know how I could delete some documents selectively then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is now, how could I delete all these documents without deleting the collection?

There is no way in which you can delete an entire collection without deleting all documents that exist under that particualr collection. So first delete all documents and the collection will be deleted automatically. In case of large collections I recommend you delete the documents in smaller chunks. This is happening client side, however you can write a function in [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) to achieve the same thing server side.

**Edit:**

According to the official documentation regarding on [how to delete collections](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data) using Javascript:

> Deleting collections from a Web client is not recommended.

So if you have only a few documents, iterate through the collection and call `delete()` on each document reference otherwise I recommend you Cloud Functions.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer! This is exactly what I want though, to delete all documents from a collection. How could I do that?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but just to make this clear I didnt want to delete the collection!

Comment: Once the last document is deleted, the collection it self is beeing deleted. You cannot keep an empty collection. Is it clear now?

Comment: If want to delete only some documents selectively, as I already told you, you should find those documents first and call delete() function on that document referece.

Comment: So I recommend you make your own attempt given the information in the answer/comments and ask another question if something else comes up.